# How to merge multiple row into one row based on two columns

Tags: python, pandas, merge, aggregate

I have a data frame that has 10 columns and 1000 rows. I am trying to merge two specific rows into one single row based on date and ID
The data frame is like this

```
Id Name Product Date revenue

1 John  P1      2022-02-01 50
1 John  P2     2022-02-01 10
2 Joe   P1     2022-01-01 60
2 Joe   P2     2022-02-01 10
2 Joe   P3     2022-03-01 20


What I want the output as 

Id Name Product Date revenue
1 John  P1,P2     2022-02-01 60
2 Joe   P1,P2,P3  2022-03-01 90

I tried `groupby`, `apply` and `ffill()`. What I am struggling with is to have products as P1,P2,P3 in one single row by their latest date. Any suggestions?
```

Comment: Please double check that you really intentionally undid the apparently helpful formatting improvements by another user.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple aggregations in a pandas groupby

```
df.groupby(['Id','Name']).agg({'Product':list,'Date':max,'revenue':sum})
        Product Date    revenue
Id  Name            
1   John    [P1, P2]    2022-01-01  60
2   Joe [P1, P2, P3]    2022-03-01  90
```

Comment: I tried multiple aggregations and my output only shows one product  as `1 John P2 2022-02-01 10 `

Answer (score 1):

Try aggregating each column with the desired function:

```
#convert to datetime if needed
df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])

output = df.groupby(["ID","Name"],as_index=False).agg({"Product": ",".join, 
                                                       "Date":"max",
                                                       "Revenue":"sum"})

>>> output

   ID  Name   Product       Date  Revenue
0   1  John     P1,P2 2022-02-01       60
1   2   Joe  P1,P2,P3 2022-03-01       90
```